# Access Multi Repository in Azure DevOps Classic Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-repos

We are using Classic Azure DevOps Pipeline(Due to organization restriction). Normally we can use multiple repose in yaml during setup but same doesn't apply to Classic. I wanted to other repo in same project in my classic pipeline.

I got this Document from Microsoft for accessing additional repo [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic). I followed the same steps. Added script task with  git clone -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)"  [Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlGoJ.png) and enabled oauth
[Oauth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrU4y.png)

```
Starting: Bash Script
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.214.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
git clone -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" "https://Project@dev.azure.com/Project/DevOps%20Integration%20Demo/_git/DevOps%20Integration%20Demo"
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" -c pwd
/d/a/_temp
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" /d/a/_temp/d0ad30a0-9750-4561-9854-3bb4d4da9743.sh
Cloning into 'DevOps%20Integration%20Demo'...
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier DevOps Integration Demo does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository 'https://dev.azure.com/Project/DevOps%20Integration%20Demo/_git/DevOps%20Integration%20Demo/' not found
##[error]Bash exited with code '128'.
Finishing: Bash Script
```

I get the error while running the pipeline. This Project is accessible and I am Project Administrator of the project. How to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the issue using

> git clone
> `https://:$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProj/_git/MyRepoYou`

Need to Disable Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines setting in project pipeline for cloning in classic Pipeline

[Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsWzz.png)